# Problem with imap_fetchstructure(): Bad message number

Tags: php, gmail, imap, gmail-imap

I'm working on IMAP reading email from mine google account, and can't find a way to check is email with exact number exists or why this errors happens.

Here is my code, so basically I make an connection than search all email go get list of them which are from specific sender list, and then run process function

```
$mail_conn = imap_open($this->hostname, $this->username, $this->password);
```

...

```
$emails = imap_search($mail_conn, 'FROM ' . $sender, SE_UID);
$results = $this->process($mail_conn, $emails);
```

Process function looks like this

....

```
            foreach ($emails as $email_number)
            {
            $email_structure = imap_fetchstructure($mail_conn, $email_number, FT_UID);
```

.....

I tried to remove  FT_UID but same error persists. What could be your suggestion what to do?

What I get when I debug is:

In emails imap_search returns

```
[emails] => Array
    (
        [0] => 513384
        [1] => 513501
        [2] => 514079
    )
```

I start process this id

```
[email_number] => 513384
```

after that error occurs.

Comment: Have you tried to put all code next to each other? And what's in `$emails`? If you search with `SE_UID` you can fetch by UID with `imap_fetchstructure` and the `FT_UID` option. Otherwise you need to provide the message number. But in any case, $email_number is wrong, hence the error. Put the code next to each other so you're sure you're operating on the same connection etc..

Comment: I have this in emails[emails] => Array
 (
  [0] => 513384
  [1] => 513501
  [2] => 514074
  [3] => 514075
  [4] => 514076
 ) so it's array with id's once when imap_fetchstructure() called it's use first id from emails, but fails.

Comment: So basically connection is same, resource is that what imap_search has been returned, but once when I start process it it fails...

Comment: vaske, just to ensure it all is the same: var_dump both times $mail_conn. Just for safety.

Comment: yup both time same Resource id #129 ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm experiencing same problem and following seem to help:

Replace your search call

```
$emails = imap_search($mail_conn, 'FROM ' . $sender, SE_UID);
```

with sort call with search criteria

```
$emails = imap_sort($mail_conn, SORTARRIVAL, 0, null, 'FROM ' . $sender);
```

Note that if option SE_UID is specified (instead of null which i have there) it stops working for some reason...

Comment: I still have same problem with this.

Answer (score 0):

Function imap_sort have format:

```
imap_sort ($imap_stream, $criteria, $reverse, $options = 0, $search_criteria = null, $charset = 'NIL')
```

You must be use: `imap_sort ($mail_conn, SORTARRIVAL, 0, SE_UID, 'FROM ' . $sender)`